# How to use node.js fetch data from mongodb and push retrieved data into an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How to use node.js fetch data from mongodb and push retrieved data into an array ? I have user collection in mongodb and I can fetch the user and its USER_SECRET and PAS_SECRET information by email without problem to display them in a form, but I was failed to push USER_SECRET and PASS_SECRET of user into a users [] array . I Got error 500.

```
     //-----login ui form-----
     router.get("/user/login", function (req, res) {
     res.render("users/login.ejs");
     });
    //------ Post ---
    router.post("/user_secret", async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.username;
    console.log(email);
    users = [];
    try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ USER_SECRET: email });
    if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).send("Inputs are Incorrect Information");
     }
    // res.render("users/addOrEdit", { user });// this works
       res.users.push({
       username: user.USER_SECRET,
       password: user.PASS_SECRET,
     });
    } catch (e) {
     res.status(500).send();
     }
    });

    I could not find the reason of failure. Should I use map method ?
    How to check if the users [] has data or not ? Please help.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `res.users` is undefined...so after getting the user, you can write:

```
res.status(200).send([{
  username: user.USER_SECRET,
  password: user.PASS_SECRET
}])
```

Instead of:

```
res.users.push({ ... })
```

Comment: I removed the res. from  res.users.push({.......and like : 
  users.push({
      username: user.USER_SECRET,
      password: user.PASS_SECRET,
    });
    console.log(users[0]);

    res.redirect("/")   and work but I do not know if it is a right way ?